# tcp network not work after build the game in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp, server, client

I implement the tcp network on my game when I make the test on editor every thing is work but after the build nothing works.

I have try multiple times change the code to make it work, but it seems I am missing something in my code.

Also I have use debug.log to control the actions on it and every thing work fine in editor but not in the build, I have built it in the 2 versions the normal version and a debug version.

There are no errors in my code.

In the debug version the debug.log not work at all.

This is my server code

```
using System;
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Sockets; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading; 
using UnityEngine;  
using UnityEngine.UI;  

public class TCPTestServer : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    #region private members     
    /// <summary>   
    /// TCPListener to listen for incoming TCP connection   
    /// requests.   
    /// </summary>  
    public TcpListener tcpListener; 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Background thread for TcpServer workload.   
    /// </summary>  
    public Thread tcpListenerThread;    
    /// <summary>   
    /// Create handle to connected tcp client.  
    /// </summary>  
    public TcpClient connectedTcpClient;    
    #endregion  
    public Text ipadresstoconnect;
    public InputField inputip;
    public InputField inputport;
    public Text iptext;
    public int port;
    public Image online;
    public Image offline;
    public string ipv4 = IPManager.GetIP(ADDRESSFAM.IPv4);
    public bool isclienton;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {       
        // Start TcpServer background thread        
        //tcpListenerThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(ListenForIncomingRequests));      
        //tcpListenerThread.IsBackground = true;        
        //tcpListenerThread.Start(); 

        iptext.text = ipv4;
        inputip.text = ipv4;
        inputport.text = "8052";
        online.enabled = false;
        offline.enabled = true;
        port = 8052;
    }   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {   
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
        {             
            SendMessage();         
        }
        if (connectedTcpClient != null) 
        {             
            isclienton=true;
            isclientconnect();
        }

    }   

    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background TcpServerThread; Handles incoming TcpClient requests     
    /// </summary>  
    public void ListenForIncomingRequests () 
    {       
        try 
        {           
            // Create listener on localhost port 8052.

            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ipv4), port);             
            tcpListener.Start();              
            Debug.Log("Server is listening");              
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];              
            while (true) 
            {               
                using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()) 
                {                   
                    // Get a stream object for reading                  
                    using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream()) 
                    {                       
                        int length;                         
                        // Read incoming stream into byte arrary.                       
                        while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) 
                        {                           
                            var incomingData = new byte[length];                            
                            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incomingData, 0, length);                              
                            // Convert byte array to string message.                            
                            string clientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingData);                          
                            Debug.Log("client message received as: " + clientMessage);                      
                        }                   
                    }               
                }           
            }       
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) 
        {           
            Debug.Log("SocketException " + socketException.ToString());         
        }     
    }   

    /// <summary>   
    /// Send message to client using socket connection.     
    /// </summary>  
    public void SendMessage() 
    {       
        if (connectedTcpClient == null) 
        {             
            return;         
        }       

        try 
        {           
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream();          
            if (stream.CanWrite) 
            {                 
                string serverMessage = "This is a message from your server.";           
                // Convert string message to byte array.                 
                byte[] serverMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverMessage);               
                // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.               
                stream.Write(serverMessageAsByteArray, 0, serverMessageAsByteArray.Length);               
                Debug.Log("Server sent his message - should be received by client");           
            }       
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) 
        {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }   
    }

    public void SendMessage2() 
    {       
        if (connectedTcpClient == null) 
        {             
            return;         
        }       

        try 
        {           
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream();          
            if (stream.CanWrite) 
            {                 
                string serverMessage = "A new server is about start listen in -->" + ipadresstoconnect.text.ToString();             
                // Convert string message to byte array.                 
                byte[] serverMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverMessage);               
                // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.               
                stream.Write(serverMessageAsByteArray, 0, serverMessageAsByteArray.Length);               
                Debug.Log("Server has sent the message...");
                isclienton=false;
            }       
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) 
        {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }   
    }

    public void start_server()
    {
        // Start TcpServer background thread        
        tcpListenerThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(ListenForIncomingRequests));        
        tcpListenerThread.IsBackground = true;      
        tcpListenerThread.Start();
        SendMessage2 ();
    }

    public void isclientconnect()
    {
        if (isclienton=true) 
        {
            if (connectedTcpClient != null) 
            {             
                SendMessage2();          
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my client code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TCPTestClient : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    #region private members     
    public TcpClient socketConnection;  
    public Thread clientReceiveThread;  
    #endregion      
    public Text nickname;
    public int id;
    public string ipv4_v2 = IPManager.GetIP(ADDRESSFAM.IPv4);

    // Use this for initialization  
    void Start () 
    {
        //ConnectToTcpServer();     
    }   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {         
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
        {             
            SendMessage();         
        }     
    }   

    /// <summary>   
    /// Setup socket connection.    
    /// </summary>  
    public void ConnectToTcpServer () 
    {       
        try 
        {           
            clientReceiveThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(ListenForData));          
            clientReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;            
            clientReceiveThread.Start();        
        }       
        catch (Exception e) 
        {           
            Debug.Log("On client connect exception " + e);      
        }   
    }   

    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background clientReceiveThread; Listens for incoming data.  
    /// </summary>     
    public void ListenForData() 
    {       
        try 
        {           
            socketConnection = new TcpClient("169.254.87.130", 8052);           
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];             
            while (true) 
            {               
                // Get a stream object for reading              
                using (NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream()) 
                {                   
                    int length;                     
                    // Read incoming stream into byte arrary.                   
                    while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) 
                    {                       
                        var incomingData = new byte[length];                        
                        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incomingData, 0, length);                      
                        // Convert byte array to string message.                        
                        string serverMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingData);                      
                        Debug.Log("server message received as: " + serverMessage);                  
                    }               
                }           
            }         
        }         
        catch (SocketException socketException) 
        {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }     
    }   

    /// <summary>   
    /// Send message to server using socket connection.     
    /// </summary>  
    public void SendMessage() 
    {         
        if (socketConnection == null) 
        {             
            return;         
        }       
        try 
        {           
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream();            
            if (stream.CanWrite) 
            {                 
                string clientMessage = "This is a message from one of your clients.";               
                // Convert string message to byte array.                 
                byte[] clientMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientMessage);               
                // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.                 
                stream.Write(clientMessageAsByteArray, 0, clientMessageAsByteArray.Length);                 
                Debug.Log("Client sent his message - should be received by server");             
            }         
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) 
        {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }     
    }

    public void connect()
    {
        ConnectToTcpServer();
    }

    public void SendMessageonconnect() 
    {         
        if (socketConnection == null) 
        {             
            return;         
        }       
        try 
        {           
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream();            
            if (stream.CanWrite) 
            {                 
                string clientMessage = nickname.ToString();                 
                // Convert string message to byte array.                 
                byte[] clientMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientMessage);               
                // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.                 
                stream.Write(clientMessageAsByteArray, 0, clientMessageAsByteArray.Length);                 
                Debug.Log("Client sent his message - should be received by server-->" + nickname.text.ToString());             
            }         
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) 
        {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The lines that start the `tcpListenerThread` in the server code and call `ConnectToTcpServer();` in the client code are commented out. 
There are two methods `start_server()` and `connect()` which do not seem to be called.
This is probably why in the build it does not work.

Moreover, you have not implemented a routine to kill those processes when your app quits, and Unity does not keep track of the threads you create and does not kill them on its own. This might be the reason why your app seems to work in the editor. I suppose you first ran it with those lines, then them commented out later. In subsequent times you hit *play*, the threads are still running from the first time.

You should absolutely implement some kind of routines to kill them when you are finished with those threads.

Comment: tank you for the replay in fact i call the start_server and connect with button

Comment: @helderventura From another script? Are you sure they are called? The problem might be there. What Debug messages do you find in `output.txt`?

Comment: yes also i send the screenshoot of it in action https://imgur.com/odl17pf

Comment: This is in the editor. Debul.Log messages also get sent in final build. You can find them in a .txt file named `output.txt` that you can find in your build's Data directory. This can help find where your app does not work in build.

Comment: i finnaly find the file you mean and i see an error there Platform assembly: C:\Users\Media Ads Labs.MediaAdsLabs-PC.000\Desktop\wizard_Data\Managed\System.Configuration.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Media Ads Labs.MediaAdsLabs-PC.000\Desktop\wizard_Data\Managed\System.Xml.dll (this message is harmless)
SocketException System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Comment: The problem might be that there still are leftover threads running. Try rebooting your pc, and then running the build ONCE. If it works, and subsequent runs do not, the problem is that you left th threads running. If it doesn't check that the error on output.txt is still the same.

Comment: i did restart the computer and look for the file its look like its work now after to me restart the computer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198152/discussion-between-kefren-and-helder-ventura).

Answer (score 0):

Even if this question is old - I recently ran into a similar problem and want to share what the issue was.

1. If you build to Android, make sure the internet connection is enabled in the player profile
2. Unity seems to have a virtual network when applications "run from the editor". So you not only have to build the client, but also the server application. A build client can not connect to a "run in editor" server.